# MySQL select from text column with filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I would like to query a database which is MySQL 5.

Let's say database name is `db` and the table name is `table` and the column name is `column`

and that column is a `text`

**containing the following for example:**

```
aksksksksjsjk&ct=100&rxp=0918&rpa=100
aksksksksjsjk&ct=100&rxp=1018&ls=1
```

So i would like to query that table and grep only where rxp `>` `0918`

**so I'm expecting the result to be:**

```
aksksksksjsjk&ct=100&rxp=1018&ls=1
```

I tried with `SELECT column FROM db.table WHERE column LIKE '%rxp=1018%'`and it's working ! but that's meant that i will need to manually insert all dates !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the value that comes after `rxp=` is always of length 4 in the format `MMYY` then the following should do the trick for you. Note that since your date is in string format, we need to perform check for both the month and year separately.

```
SELECT *
FROM db.table
WHERE LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testColumn, 'rxp=', -1), 2)  > '09' 
    AND MID(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testColumn, 'rxp=', -1), 3, 2)  >= '18'
```

Assuming you've got the following values under `column`:

```
aksksksksjsjk&ct=100&rxp=0918&rpa=100
aksksksksjsjk&ct=100&rxp=1018&ls=1
aksksksksjsjk&ct=100&rxp=1116&ls=1
```

The output of the query should be

```
aksksksksjsjk&ct=100&rxp=1018&ls=1
```

However, I would highly recommend you to normalise your table and store every value in a separate column (`ct`, `rxp`, `rpa`, `ls` etc.) instead of having a lot of information combined into a single string.

Comment: you mentioned `FROM db.table A` so what is `A` refer to ?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp(
Integ Integer
 )
insert into #temp values(CONVERT(INT, right(left('aksksksksjsjk&ct=100&rxp=0918&rpa=100', 29),4)) ) ,
                        (CONVERT(INT, right(left('aksksksksjsjk&ct=100&rxp=1018&ls=1', 29),4)) ) 
select * from #temp
where Integ >918
drop table #temp
```

hope it helps you